# Adding fence section on 45 degree angle

Tags: fence

I live in a condo development and our patios are next to each other. Our neighbor recently removed some bushes that helped with the privacy. There exists two 8 foot sections of fence between the patios but we would like to add a third section on a 45 degree angle where the bushes were removed.

The companies that I have spoken with so far   are telling me job is too small, or another post will need to be added and there will be a gap. Minimum labor of $600 plus material.

**Question:** Is there a way to cut into the  existing post and run the new section of fence at 45 degree angle?  (*that is if i can find matching fence*).

[image]

Hope this uploads and helps...where those small arbs are located my neighbor removed some larger shrubs that provided more privacy

Comment: We need to have thorough understanding of how your fence is constructed before we can advise you on how to make changes/additions to it.

Comment: Steve, you're now posting under two accounts, and that shouldn't have been posted as an answer. Please edit your question to add the photo, and take the [tour] to see how we operate.

Answer (score 2):

The vinyl fence has proprietary hardware for attaching the panels. If you can determine the brand and source parts, I'm sure they'll have skewed connectors for you.

Otherwise, get your carpentry on. Rip the edge off a panel at a 45 degree angle using a table saw or a circular saw with a clamped board as a guide. Mount the uncut edge to the new post per the hardware manufacturer's instructions, and mount the cut edge to the existing post with countersunk corrosion-resistant screws. Optionally add vinyl screw caps to pan-head screws.

You've asked a broad question, so I'm only able to provide a general answer. If you like, revise your post with more detail and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the pictured post with a wooden one that you trim at a 45 degree angle to receive the new panel.

You could use a roll-up privacy screen that you attach to the existing post, that could be unrolled in any direction but would need something solid to attach to at the other end.  It's like a sideways outdoor roller blind.

A picture of the entire setting, showing both patios and both ends of the desired new piece especially what it might attach to, would help.

Also --- most condos would not allow you to add or modify fencing.  Make sure this is allowed.  Some condos require certain types of shrubbery in certain places, and it's possible this is such an example.  Check for that too, maybe he has to put it back.